# Dialogflow web client

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to call into my Dialogflow app from a web page. The V1 API does not seem to support CORS, but the "Try this API" box on the [detectIntent API reference page](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent?apix=true) shows a Javascript example which includes `<script>` and `<button>` DOM elements, so I assume that V2 does support CORS.

I'm a little confused about the OAuth 2.0 authentication though - is the user required to log into a Google account?

The [v2-auth-setup page](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup) walks you through the process of creating a service account and saving the JSON private key file, but I have 2 concerns:

1. The "Permissions" panel on the cloud console "Service accounts" page implies that the service account inherits "Editor", "Owner", "Compute Engine Service Agent" and other roles - but this service account should not inherit any roles, it should be locked right down.
2. This all implies that I need to serve the "secrets.json" file to the general public. Even if it is just a restricted service account, that doesn't seem right.

Perhaps I'm not understanding this bit correctly?

```
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
```

...does that mean that when the following is called the user (even if they don't have a Google account) is logged in as "YOUR_CLIENT_ID" without any login popups/redirects?

```
 gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dialogflow"})
```

...The Dialogflow console provides V1 client and developer access tokens, but where do I get YOUR_CLIENT_ID from?